# Rename extension file in PowerShell error

Tags: powershell

I want to change the extension of file. When I execute the code from PowerShell ISE, it works. But when I execute it under WinPE, it return this error:

```
+ ... Found = $Job | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.que','.pro')}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (P:\JOB\FS190723...WQ6BT602-A1.que:String) [Rename-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

This the output before rename the file. To make sure the connection ready, and the file is exist.

```
Connection Ready
P:\JOB\FS190723AG_1062E59622CA_AAA111222-A1.que
```

```
[xml]$Config_File = Get-Content .\ConfigUnit.xml
function PRO_JOB {
    if (Check_Connection_PRISM) {
        Write-Host "Connection Ready"
        $Job_Path = $Config_File.Automation_ConfigUnit.Path.JOB_Path
        $Job = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Job_Path\*$b_SN`_$b_MAC*.que"
        Write-Host $Job
        pause
        Write-Host "Rename file .que to .pro"
        $Job_Found = $Job | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.que','.pro')}
    }
```

Comment: Check the permissions on the file.